# How do I clear this error?

Tags: java

I'm using Java and my program is supposed to ask a user to enter an number 1-10. If the number isn't in ranger, it suppose to display an error message. Also it's supposed to  display that chosen number in Pinyun. My error comes from int number = keyboard.nextInt();

Here's the rest of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ForReal {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter an number");
        int number = keyboard.nextInt();


        while (number < 1 || number > 10) 
            System.out.print("Error, choose a number between 1-10");

        switch (number)
        {
        case 1 : System.out.println("The English numberal 1" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral yil1"); 
                                                    break;

        case 2:  System.out.println("The English numeral 2" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral er4");  
                                                    break;

        case 3: System.out.println("The English numeral 3" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral san1");
                                                    break;
        case 4: System.out.println("The English numeral 4" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral si4");
                                                    break;
        case 5: System.out.println("The English numeral 5" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral wu3");
                                                    break;
        case 6: System.out.println("The English numeral 6" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral liu4");
                                                    break;
        case 7: System.out.println("The English numeral 7" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral qil");
                                                    break;
        case 8: System.out.println("The English numeral 8" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral bal");
                                                    break;
        case 9: System.out.println("The Arabic numeral 9" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral jiu3");
                                                    break;
        case 10: System.out.println("The Arabic numeral 10" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral shi2");
                                                    break;



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It's int number = keyboard.nextInt();

Comment: Your question has been answered, but for future reference, you will always want to tell us the complete error message as well as the line causing the error. It makes sense that the better, quicker and easier that we can understand your problems, the better and quicker we can help.

Answer (score 3):

You're re-declaring `number` twice. Get rid of the first declaration at the top. This one:

```
int number;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to define twice the `int` number.

Either remove the first declaration or change the line:

```
int number = keyboard.nextInt();
```

with

```
number = keyboard.nextInt();
```

You may also want to wrap the call in a try and catch to check for the expected exception coming from the [Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = keyboard.nextInt();
while (number < 1 || number > 10) 
    System.out.print("Error, choose a number between 1-10");
```

This will not work: It will just print message for ever, because number value isn't changing inside this loop.

Comment: 1+ and *always* enclose every if block and loop inside curly braces, even one line loops, especially early on.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first things first.

*My error comes from int number = keyboard.nextInt();*

Well, it's nice to know on which line u get error, but *what* error would be even better, just copy the error message to the question, probably `variable number is already defined` or something like that

There could be another error on this line, `InputMismatchException` can be thorwn if you type something that isnt integer number

```
while (number < 1 || number > 10) 
System.out.print("Error, choose a number between 1-10");
```

this will not change the value of number, change to

```
while (number < 1 || number > 10) {
    System.out.print("Error, choose a number between 1-10");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

and finally:

```
case 1 : System.out.println("The English numberal 1" + number + " converts to the pinyin numeral yil1"); 
     break;
```

*Seriously?* Programing was inventer for lazy people so then can tell computer to do work them, although programming like this is possible, try to avoid duplicity (same code on more places) like this.